# Data pass between viewpager fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am created one viewpager activity. It have three fragments. Each Fragment have one editText and last fragment have  button. When I click Submit button I want to display first two fragments detail which I entered using model class.

Comment: try to use sender class fragment.setArguments() and receiving class getArguments

Comment: can you send any example or link to refer this?

Comment: yeah sure.......

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-viewpager-to-create-a-sliding-screen-ui-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

You should store the values in the container `Activity` and then, update the last `Fragment` with the information.

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you send any example or link to refer this?